# Module Not FoundError Python Django

Tags: python, django, url, mapping

I am trying to map the base URL to my "Learning Logs's" home page. here is the following code I have in my main *urls.py file:*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r' ', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),
]
```

I save the file and look at the terminal to see if there are any issues and it spits out the following error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learning_logs.urls'**

I am no to python/django and following a book called the python crash course. not sure what I am doing wrong please help!

Comment: learning_logs is one of my APPS and I added this in my settings.py file. how would I import my APP here?

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. You just need to have another `urls.py` but in the `learning_logs` app directory. Take a look at this example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views

Comment: Thanks man. I was missing the the following: app_name = 'learning_logs' in my urls.py file in the learning_logs directory.... Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is check author's updates:
http://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/chapter_18/README.html#updates

updates for *urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```

Updates for *learning_logs/urls.py*

```
"""Defines url patterns for learning_logs."""

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page.
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```